# Python code issue with looping more dates in list

Tags: python, list, algorithm, numpy, for-loop

I have some problems if I use so many 'Materials' or Codes, with 50 random codes from my list, everything is fine, but if I use all lists with 461 codes I receive results like NaN.
Somewhere I make something wrong but where.
If somebody can support me, I will be very thankful to you.

I use 7 dates with 10_000 rows and 4 columns.

Memory usage is: 1.1 MB

I try many things, but, unfortunately I don't have enough experience in Python.

My code is below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob

file_paths = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\vedran.djuric\Desktop\Novi test\*.csv')

dfs = []
for file_path in file_paths:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, usecols=['Material', 
                                     'Posting Date',
                                     'Qty in Un. of Entry',
                                     'Plant'],
    dtype = {'Material':'category', 
             'Posting Date':'category', 
             'Qty in Un. of Entry':'float32', 
             'Plant':'int16'})

    dfs.append(df)
    ALL = pd.concat(dfs)

ALL['Posting Date'] = pd.to_datetime(ALL['Posting Date'])
ALL['Qty in Un. of Entry'] = abs(ALL['Qty in Un. of Entry'])

ALL.rename(columns = {'Material':'Code',  
                 'Posting Date':'Date', 
                 'Qty in Un. of Entry':'sell_ea', 
               }, inplace = True)
print(ALL.head())
print(ALL.shape)

def pivot_tables(plant):
   
    filt = ALL[ALL['Plant'] == plant]
    df = pd.pivot_table(filt, values='sell_ea', index='Date', columns='Code', aggfunc='sum')
    df = df.fillna(0)
    df.reset_index(inplace=True) 
     
    return df

print(sorted(ALL.Plant.unique())) 

df_4601 = pivot_tables(4601).iloc[:,1:] 
df_4602 = pivot_tables(4602).iloc[:,1:] 
df_4603 = pivot_tables(4603).iloc[:,1:] 
df_4604 = pivot_tables(4604).iloc[:,1:] 
df_4605 = pivot_tables(4605).iloc[:,1:] 
df_4606 = pivot_tables(4606).iloc[:,1:] 
df_4607 = pivot_tables(4607).iloc[:,1:] 

list_df = [df_4601, df_4602, df_4603, df_4604, df_4605, df_4606, df_4607]

def filter_outliers(df):
    df_filtered = df.copy()   

    for column in df.columns:
        q1 = df[column].quantile(0.25)
        q3 = df[column].quantile(0.75)
        iqr = q3 - q1
        lower_bound = q1 - (1.5 * iqr)
        upper_bound = q3 + (1.5 * iqr)

        df_filtered = df_filtered[df_filtered[column].between(lower_bound, upper_bound,    inclusive='both')]  
    
    return df_filtered

all_means = []
for df in list_df:
    df_filtered = filter_outliers(df)

    means = {}
    for column in df_filtered.columns:
        mean = df_filtered[column].mean()
        means[column] = mean

    data = [(k, v) for k, v in means.items()]

    means_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['column', 'mean'], index=range(len(means)))

    all_means.append(means_df)

final_df = pd.concat(all_means, axis=1)

final_df.columns = ['Code', '4601', 'Code', '4602', 'Code', '4603', 'Code', '4604', 
                'Code', '4605', 'Code', '4606', 'Code', '4607']

print(final_df)
```

I try many things, but, unfortunately I don't have enough experience in Python.
I expect somebody to support me on how to solve this issue.

Comment: "I expect somebody to support me on how to solve this issue." We are volunteers, I'd tone that down.

Comment: @paisance, do bare in mind that not everyone posting on SO has English as a first language. I doubt Vedran intended to be rude or entitled and was merely asking if someone could help as best he could. At least give him the benefit of the doubt.